# Mysql PDO Fetching values and related values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I am trying to fetch in one query values of a table and related values from another table. Below is my code so far

```
    $stm = $conn->prepare("
SELECT *, COUNT(table3_input_id) AS variationsNo FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON  `table1_id` = `table2_ref` 
LEFT JOIN `table3` ON `table2_id`=`table3_input_id`
WHERE   `table1_id`=:bindtable1ID 
 GROUP by `table3_input_id` ORDER by `table1_id` ASC");
$stm->bindValue(":bindtable1ID", $preditcion_id);
$stm->execute();
$inputList = $stm->fetchAll();
foreach ($inputList as $row) {
  -- fetch values from table 1
  while(....){
        -fetch values from table 2 related to table 1
    }
}
```

So I want to list values from table 2 and if table 2 has related values in table 3, i want to list them under the table 2 value

1. Table 2 value 1
2. Table 2 value 2
3. Table 2 value 3

   1. Table 2 related values from table 3
   2. Table 2 related values from table 3
   3. Table 2 related values from table 3
4. Table 2 value 4
5. Table 2 value 5

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how can I list the output exampled with my query, I think I need two foreaches, one for table 2 values and one for table 2 related values from table 3?